# VBA Dictionary Object If Exists Not Working

Tags: vba, dictionary, object, exists

I am comparing elements in a column to a dictionary object (`ProjectList`) in Excel VBA. I am printing out the keys to the debug window:

```vb
For Each X In ProjectList.Keys
    Debug.Print X, ProjectList(X)
Next X
```

And it prints a key "A123".

I am using the Exists function to see if "A123" is in the dictionary:

```vb
X = "A123"

If ProjectList.exists(X) = False Then
    do something
end if
```

The procedure keeps getting to the "do something" line as if it does not find X in the dictionary even though it is clearly in there because the debug loop prints it out. What am I doing wrong here?  Any help appreciated!

Comment: `And it prints a key "A123"` - it should print two things. What are those two things?

Comment: how did you populate the dictionary? Where did the keys come from?  You may have invisible characters that don't show when you print to the immediate widow.

Comment: @GSerg it prints the value and the index: "a123    100".  There are four spaces in between but if I look at the values in the locals section, there are no spaces in the value.  I also am trimming the cell value just to make sure.

Comment: @freeflow I printed both values and they are identical

Comment: @Crash `a123` is different from `A123`.

Answer (score 0):

I added a trim statement to the section that fills the dictionary.

```
For ThisRow = 2 To LastRow
    ProjectList.Add Key:=Trim(FSht.Cells(ThisRow, 1)), Item:=ThisRow
Next ThisRow
```

I have no idea why that helped because the values in the spreadsheet have no spaces, the locals window showed no spaces... I am totally confused why this worked but it did.

Comment: `Key:=FSht.Cells(ThisRow, 1)` adds the Range object, not the value.  Hence the value doesn't exist.  Use the Value property of the Range object like this `Key:=FSht.Cells(ThisRow, 1).Value`.